# DataTables jquery addon dissapears after partialpage is updated with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

I have a table, which I want to use along with the [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin. Actually, it works really good, and I can use all the functionality as is.

Unfortunately, my table reside in a partialview, because I thought it was neat to utilize AJAX to update the partial viewm when I do basic operations in my table such as Delete and edit.

### Now to the issue:

The first time I load my page with the partial view, DataTables attach and works. However, if I delete or edit my entities, causing AJAX to update the partial view, the functionality dissapears.

I though that I could solve this, by attaching the `DataTables()` function to the "static" div that wraps my partial view, and then find the table class, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#partialViewWrapper" ).find( ".table" ).DataTable({
        paging: false,
        info: false
    });
});
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Therefore, I would like to know, how I can attach DataTables to my table, in a way so that updating my partial view will not "detach" the plugin.

Comment: Not clear but It seems like a scoping issue here ! Are you using ajax.reload() https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload() ? [ the functionality dissapears] what does disappear... the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refresh your datatable after delete/edit. you can use load/reload/draw as per your requirement.

1.If your ajax data url are same. Then try

```
    yourDataTable.draw();

    OR 

    yourDataTable.ajax.reload();
```

2. If your need to update ajax data url. Then try

   ```
   yourDataTable.ajax.url(newUrl).draw();
   OR
   var myParams = yourDataTable.ajax.params();
   yourDataTable.ajax.url(newUrl, myParams).load();//if no parameter then pass null
   ```