# Delete row in table using ajax in asp.net mvc without postback in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I want to delete a row in my table without post-back. I am using jquery datatables. 
I have a garbage icon where I want to ask the user to confirm delete. There are some scenarios where the delete is not possible so after the user confirms I want to show a message that tells the user that the delete was not possible or that it succeeded.

Here is a visual representation of my table. 
[image: My table]

Here is my datatable code.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#proveedorTable').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/fichaproveedor/loaddata",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "proveedor_id", "autoWidth": true },   /* index = 0 */
                    { "data": "nombre", "autoWidth": true },      /* index = 1 */
                    { "data": "direccion", "autoWidth": true },  /* index = 2 */
                    { "data": "codigo_postal", "autoWidth": true },  /* index = 3 */
                    { "data": "cuidad", "autoWidth": true },  /* index = 4 */
                    { "data": "pais", "autoWidth": true },  /* index = 5 */
                    { "data": "pagina_internet", "autoWidth": true },  /* index = 6 */
                    {
                        "data": "proveedor_id", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                            return '<a class="btn" href="/fichaproveedor/AnadirEditar/' + data + '"><i class="material-icons" title="Detalles">edit</i></a>';   /* index = 7 */
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "proveedor_id", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                            return '<a class="popup" href="/fichaproveedor/Eliminar/' + data + '"><i class="material-icons" title="Eliminar">delete</i></a>';   /* index = 8 */
                        }
                    },
                    { "defaultContent": "", "autoWidth": true }, 
                ],
                'columnDefs': [{
                    'targets': [7,8,9], /* column index */
                    'orderable': false, /* true or false */
                }]
            })
</script>
```

Here is my asp.net mvc code.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Eliminar(int id)
    {
        proveedorContext proveedorContext = new proveedorContext();

        var proveedorFound = proveedorContext.GetAllProveedor().Where(a => a.proveedor_id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        var proveedorsData = proveedorContext.GetAllProveedor();
        if (proveedorFound != null)
        {
            proveedorContext.deleteProveedorFromDB(proveedorFound);
            return Json(new { succes = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json( new { succes = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Eliminar")]
    public ActionResult EliminarFromDB(int id)
    {
        proveedorContext proveedorContext = new proveedorContext();

        var proveedorFound = proveedorContext.GetAllProveedor().Where(a => a.proveedor_id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        var proveedorsData = proveedorContext.GetAllProveedor();
        if (proveedorFound != null)
        {

            proveedorContext.deleteProveedorFromDB(proveedorFound);
            return Json( new { succes = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { succes = false } };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Change  your delete button like--

```
{
  "data": "proveedor_id", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
 return "<a href='#' class='popup' onclick=Delete('" + data + "'); title='Eliminar'><i class='material-icons'></i>delete</a>";
}


OR

{
  "width": "50px", "render": function (data, type, row) {
 return "<a href='#' class='popup' onclick=Delete('" + row.proveedor_id + "'); title='Eliminar'><i class='material-icons'></i>delete</a>";
}
```

2.Create Delete function like--

```
    function Delete(id) {
        var url ="/fichaproveedor/Eliminar/";
        $.post(url, { id: id }, function (data) {
            if (data) {
                oTable = $('#proveedorTable').DataTable();
                oTable.draw();
            }
            else {
                alert("Something Went Wrong!");
            }
        });
    }

    //If you need confirm box use this
    function DeleteData(id) {
      var box = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ...?");
      if (box == true) {
         Delete(id);
      } else {
        //Do somthing
      }
    }
```

It's work for me. Hopefully it's working for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help I have tried  your example however the function delete does not fireup.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach sorry for my mistake. I forger you set "data": "proveedor_id". Can you try my update answer.

Comment: I have tried your new version but the the delete function still does not fireup. Mabay this will help you here is the html code that is generated  <a class="btn" href="#" onclick="Delete(3);" title="Eliminar"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>  is it correct?

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach Can you use `DeleteData` rather than `Delete`. Actually I use it. also set a debugger. Maybe the `$.post` method. and you have same action with `HttpPost` in your controller` Eliminar(int id)` and `[ActionName("Eliminar")]    EliminarFromDB(int id)`. I just copy code form my working project.

Comment: Yes you were correct I am now using deleteData and I have commented out on of my controllers and now it is working. Thank you however visually the row is still there until I refreash the page why is that and how can I fix it.

Comment: @the for refresh you need to redraw your datatable you can achieve using `datatable.draw()` method..That's belong to ` oTable = $('#proveedorTable').DataTable(); oTable.draw();`.  More Help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583033/datatables-jquery-addon-dissapears-after-partialpage-is-updated-with-ajax/60585296#60585296

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "the if condition networking." Also if I click on delete on a diffrent page I go back to the first page of the table.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach I think the code working fine for refresh. can you please check `if (data) { oTable = $('#proveedorTable').DataTable(); oTable.draw(); }`. Maybe the if condition not working. change it (`if (data)` ) as your return result.

Comment: When I do return data; in my if condition nothing happens.

Comment: I have used oTable.ajax.reload(); insded of oTable.draw(); and now the row is visually removed from datatable however my flash message is not visible until I refreash the page.

Comment: Thank you verry much for all your help it works I now have a other probleme but I will create a new question for it I added null, false in ajax.reload and now I stay on the same page